# cannot load custom-made filter , Unknown Provider error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-filter

I study the book "Angular JS by example" (pp. 79-84) and in the second chapter I created a custom-made filter.

This is the `js` file (`appModule.js`)that contains all the module declarations

```
//root module
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','7minWorkout']).
config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $sceDelegateProvider){
//...

//seven min workout app module
angular.module('7minWorkout', []);
```

This file contains the custom-made filter (`filters.js`)

```
angular.module('7minWorkout').filter('secondsToTime', function () {
//...
```

The only controller for the 7minWorkout module is in the `workout.js`

```
angular.module('7minWorkout').controller('WorkoutController',['$scope', '$interval','$location',function($scope, $interval,$location){
//...
```

and I am not using any filter inside that file

Lastly this is the view

`<h4>Workout Remaining - {{workoutTimeRemaining | secondsToTime}}</h4>`

I get

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: secondsToTimeFilterProvider <- secondsToTimeFilter`

I red [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=secondsToTimeFilterProvider) page , but I dont know how to proceed to fix this. Before creating the custom-made filter, I had no problems with my app. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you double check does `filters.js` included in your `index.html` or not?

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks. I did not think of it at all. I am a newbie and thought that I am OK because the filter is chained to the 7minWorkout module. Also the book said nothing about adding js files. All I had to do was to add `<script src="/javascripts/7MinWorkout/filters.js"></script>` in the index file

Comment: That mean its solved now?

Comment: @PankajParkar Yes man. Thanks

Comment: @PankajParkar Yeah, why not?

Comment: my answer is there in a place..Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good for me.

As you separated you various component's in each file, you need to refer those file on your index.html

You must have missed to refer `filter.js` in your index.html

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are missing reference to your files in the main html file.

Did you add references to all new javascript files that you added?

Comment: Thanks. I did not think of it at all. I am a newbie and thought that I am OK because the filter is chained to the `7minWorkout` module. Also the book said nothing about adding js files. All I had to do was to add `<script src="/javascripts/7MinWorkout/filters.js"></script>` in the index file

Comment: Awesome. If this answered your question please "approve" it as the correct answer (: